# Float from a binary file into TextField?

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield

I have a binary file I'm reading from and I want to get the balance from that file and input it into a TextField. The variable is a float, how could I do that?

Specifically from this part of the code.

```
while(true){
    ST = (SavedTrans) ois.readObject();
    viewTable.addRow(new Object[] {ST.getDate(), ST.getDrop(), ST.getCheckNo(),        
                                   ST.getDescription(), ST.getDeposit(), ST.getWithdraw(), 
                                   ST.getBalance()}
                     );
    if(ST == null){
        break;
    }
```

I'm trying to get ST.getBalance() to display on the TextField, is it even possible this way?

Comment: On a side note, checking for `null` after accessing `ST` isn't going to help much - it will have already thrown an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

*JTextField* inherits from *JTextComponent* class, therefore you should have access to the *setText()* method. This may not be the most elegant solution, but given the information available from your code, the method requires a String type parameter, so you could pass it `jTextField.setText(Float.toString((float)ST.getBalance()));`

Comment: Is there a reason it's telling me ST isn't initialized when I declared ST out of the while loop.

I put SavedTrans ST;

SavedTrans is my other file in the same folder the does the serializable. @Meraxes

EDIT: Nevermind, I just made SavedTrans ST; a global instead of in that scope.